# Where does this question fit into the new closing rules?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, close-reasons

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394315/is-this-input-option-for-select#17394315

I am not sure which category this question fits into. Is it too broad because it asks "if anyone has a better idea"? Is it unclear for the same reason it may have been too broad? Is it off topic, in that it asks for a solution without showing an attempt to solve the issue depicted?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the new Flag options mean, Question without self effort aren't off-topic anymore?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217576/do-the-new-flag-options-mean-question-without-self-effort-arent-off-topic-anym)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The appropriate close reason is *unclear what you are asking*.

There is not enough info to know what exactly the OP wants.

Comment: I voted to close based on "unclear". However, is unclear the best fit answer of the reasons? Sorry, but I am divided on this question a little. I think it is evident they want to have client side validation for the inputs to limit them to a certain range. It is just a direct request for that solution to be coded. What do you think is missing from what the OP is looking for? And moreover, should we be more concerned about what the OP wants or what the correct response is? Not trying to be negative, just trying to wrap my head around making sure I apply the correct close reasons.

Comment: I think *unclear* is the best fit because I don't get the question. Probably because OP is having trouble with his/her English. First comment on the post is *What is the question?* And second it is low quality cause of grammer and it is missing some context that I would need as a non-expert on javascript.