# Do the new Flag options mean, Question without self effort aren't off-topic anymore?

Tags: discussion, flags, off-topic

The options to post a flag as off-topic have changed, as far I noticed right.

So Q's like:

> How do I assign a value to a variable in language xyz...

As this is a absolute basic question, which indicates the OPer has raised no effort and just is too lazy to crawl through a book or tutorial.

Wouldn't Any way no more be off-topic?
As there isn't a option anymore I could categorize it to.

Comment: I agree to that, but the search tool didn't made me find that Post.

Comment: and that's why duplicates can be a good thing! I had an unfair advantage in finding it because I asked it